# PowerShell Import CA and User Certificate from pfx

Tags: powershell, pfx

I am trying to import a .p12 file using a PowerShell script. However I am not able to import the CA as it only installs the user cert and private key. I am using the following code.

```
function Import-PfxCertificate ([String]$certPath,[String]$certificateStoreLocation = "CurrentUser",[String]$certificateStoreName = "My",$pfxPassword = $null)
{
    $pfx = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2    

    $pfx.Import($certPath, $pfxPassword, "Exportable,PersistKeySet")    

    $store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store($certificateStoreName,$certificateStoreLocation)    
    $store.open("MaxAllowed")    
    $store.add($pfx)    
    $store.close()
    return $pfx
}
```

Any help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Which version of powershell are you on?  `Import-PfxCertificate` is a cmdlet that already exists.

Comment: Import-PfxCertificate will only import the certificate with matching private key. It won’t import the entire trust chain.

Comment: Mathias R - Thanks for the amended code however this still only imports the one certificate.